# bamboo create release only if manual stage is done

Tags: bamboo

I have a build with several stages. The last stage of my build is an manual stage. 
Is it possible to configure the build so that it only can create a release when the last stage has passed?

I have bamboo in version 5.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to set up another build plan that is dependent on this one (with the manual stage) then all you have to do is:

- create the second plan that will build (let's call it "*builder*")
- go to plan configuration (first build plan with manual stage)
- select `Dependencies` tab
- select the plan *builder*
- on the same page in the **Advanced Options** be sure that:
  *Trigger dependencies only when all stages have been run successfully*
  is ticked
- click save

The *Builder* plan will be triggered when the first plan finishes the manual stage.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my question was a little bit wrong and i has updated it.

Comment: in this case - if i understand it correctly - the answer should be pretty similar. you can either use deploy plans and set up a trigger (on the deploy plan side) so when all stages of your build plan finishes that triggers a deploy or you can create an other build plan that does the release and set up dependencies as i mentioned above. does it make sense?

Comment: yes it make sense, but its not a solution for my problem :D the manual stage produces 2 shared artifacts for my deploy jobs. without the artifacts the deploy job will always fail. is it possible to configure my build so that it is not possible to create a new release when the manual stage was not run?

Comment: the deploy trigger "After successful build" will only start the deploy when the manual stage is successfully finished. Do you actually want to restrict the deploy option? so it cannot be run manually unless someone finishes the manual job?

Comment: the trigger is no option for me, the job should start only manually. yes, this is what i want. btw thanks a lot for you help and patience